# Classic ASP getobject works only locally in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, asp-classic, ldap

I have a code like this:

```
User =  Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")
response.Write(User & "---<br />")
strServername = "myDomain"
Set oAD = Server.CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
strUserDN = oAD.UserName
response.Write("1: --- " & strUserDN)
'Set oAD = Nothing  

Set oUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUserDN)`
```

Locally it works in both IE and Chrome. 
From an Another computer I get an 500 error in Chrome (but it stil working in IE) The error comes on the row: `Set oUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUserDN)`
The server run IIS 7.5

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: How does User relate to strUserDN?

Comment: The user is an administrator in the AD and both server and client is part of the network (domain).